# Multiple spring core versions needed for war and dependent jar

Tags: java, spring, war

i have application code which is using java 8 and for same i have upgraded the spring version to 4.1.9, but one of the needed jar's has dependency on spring-core 3.2.4 which is why war is getting packed with 2 versions of spring jar's. due to this i am getting deployment error.

Please provide your help on below questions

1> can i force the needed jar to use spring version 4.1.9 by excluding 3.2.4 from war packaging or something?

2> can i create separate contexts for initializing the bean which i am getting from the needed jar using spring 3.2.4

Thanks

Comment: 1> Yes. --- 2> No.

Comment: i excluded the duplicate jar from getting packed into war and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend such a hybrid, even if you can manage, somehow, to get it working correctly.

What I'd do is analyse the application to discover which parts need the older version, and which parts needs the newer version. I'd then split the application in two different sub-modules, deploying them separately. This is pretty cheap if you're using containerization (e.g. Docker).

Modules can and should be able to communicate via REST, Soap, gRPC or broker (such as ActiveMQ) for messaging.

The better route is absolutely to stick to the newer version, if possible, upgrading the incompatible components.

You can also register *adapters* components which delegate to the older/to be upgraded ones. This will let you refactor the old code while maintaining a standardized interface.